# SQL Server : LEFT JOIN duplicated row

Tags: sql-server

Table: DataTable1

```
ID      SKU        QTY        
-----------------------
1       AAAA       1       
2       BBBB       1       
3       CCCC       1       
4       CCCC       1
```

Table: DataTable2

```
ID      assign_id   SKU
-----------------------------
123     99          AAAA 
124     99          CCCC
```

Is there any way to get result like this?

Thank you in advance.

```
ID      SKU        QTY     AssignID   
-----------------------------------
1       AAAA       1       99
2       BBBB       1       NULL
3       CCCC       1       99
4       CCCC       1       NULL
```

Comment: Can you share what have you tried till now?

Comment: Not using the data you have presented. There is NO data in the two tables to logically connect them to one another in ANY way, much less the way your desired output indicates.

Comment: I tried left join with distinct statement and max function. But I can only get 3 rows because of the 1st table's duplicated 'SKU' column.

Comment: What is the logic of the desired result? Are the SKUs in the first table supposed to be the same as in the 2nd one? They aren't.

Comment: I need all rows from Table1 even if there are Null values exists in the Table2. id 124 of Table2 can be mached id 3 or 4 of Table1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but probably this is what you need

```
with DataTable1(ID  ,    SKU  ,      QTY      ) as(
    select 1  ,'AAAA',     1  union all     
    select 2   ,'BBBB',    1  union all     
    select 3    ,'CCCC',   1  union all       
    select 4   ,'CCCC',    1    
),
DataTable2(ID ,     assign_id ,  SKU) as (
    select 123,     99       ,'AAA' union all
    select 124 ,    99       ,'CCC' 
)

select t.ID, t.SKU, t.QTY, case when rn = 1 then assign_id else null end as assign_id 
from (
    select DataTable1.*, DataTable2.assign_id, row_number() over(partition by DataTable1.SKU order by DataTable1.ID) as rn
    from DataTable1
    left join DataTable2
    on DataTable1.SKU like concat(DataTable2.SKU, '%')
) t
```

Comment: Perfect! You save me. Only I changed concat to cast(sku+'%' varchar) in SQL2008